# Add line pointing to important point with geom_label()

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I am working on making a line chart. I want to highlight a point on the graph by adding a text label with a line pointing to the point on the line.

Reproducible example using the R sunspot.year data:

```
dat <- data_frame(NumSunSpots = sunspot.year, Year = c(1700:1988))

dat %>% 
ggplot(aes(Year, NumSunSpots))+
geom_line()+
geom_label(aes(x = 1952, y = 175, label ="Look at what is happening!"), vjust = 1, hjust = 1)
```

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbq0y.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think it is pretty clear... My specific problem was creating a text label with a line pointing to a point on the graph. I also made an image for people that don't want to read. I don't think it can get more straightforward than that haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `geom_segment` for a simple arrow:

Play around with x, y xend and yend to bring to the desired position:

```
dat <- data_frame(NumSunSpots = sunspot.year, Year = c(1700:1988))

dat %>% 
    ggplot(aes(Year, NumSunSpots))+
    geom_line()+
    geom_label(aes(x = 1952, y = 175, label ="Look at what is happening!"), vjust = 1, hjust = 1) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = 1900, y = 250, xend = 1950, yend = 200),
                     arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm")))
```

[image]